# Cordova: how to set name of app after installation

Tags: android, cordova

I converted mobile web page to android app, but 1 question: How to config cordova that after installation on mobile phone, the app had  its name? Where it is indicated in cordova setting?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the name setting after you built apk file. You have to specify the name in [confing.xml](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/config_ref/index.html#name) like this, before conversion.

```
<widget ...>
    <name>MyApp</name>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't configure the cordova AFTER install in a mobile.

For rename your app, go to your project folder and find:
Search for the file: config.xml
And search for the tag:

```
<name>APP NAME HERE</name>
```

Don't forget to add an widget id to, in the same file, find for:

```
<widget id="com.BUSINNESNAME.YOURAPPNAME" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://........>
```

Change the "businnesname" and "yourappname" for your respective info...

Before do this, delete the "platform" folder and add it again with

- On console pointing your project root: "cordova platform add android" (if android).
- On console to: "ionic prepare android" (if android).
- And run on a mobile: "ionic run android"

More info about config.xml you can find here:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/